# Grid layout not showing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

I've been following a responsive web design tutorial and I just cant get my head round this problem. I've included the grid.css file in my html but some how chrome doesnt display it correctly. Instead of grid I get rows like in the attached image. Can someone please help me out with this? 
Thank you

[No grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4JHt.jpg)

```css
/* --------------------------- */
/* BASIC SETUP */
/* --------------------------- */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;    
}

/* --------------------------- */
/* REUSABLE COMPONENTS */
/* --------------------------- */

.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section {
    padding: 80px 0;
}

/*----- HEADINGS ----- */

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 240%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: : 1px;
    word-spacing: 4px;
    
}

/*----- BUTTONS ----- */

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 200px; 
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited {
    background-color: #e67e22;
    border: 1px solid #e67e22;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited{
    border: 1px solid #e67e22;
    color:  #e67e22;
    
}

.btn:hover, 
.btn:active {
    background-color: #cf6d17;
}

.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active {
    border: 1px solid #cf6d17;
}

.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active {
    border: 1px solid #cf6d17;
    color: #fff;
}

/* --------------------------- */
/* HEADER */
/* --------------------------- */


header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-nav {
    float:right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 8px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #cf6d17;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors-stuff%2520downloaded%2520from%2520Internet/css_downloaded/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors-stuff%2520downloaded%2520from%2520Internet/css_downloaded/grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css"> 
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,300i,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Omnifood</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
          <nav> 
              <div class="row">
                  <img src="resources/css/img/logo-white.png" alt="Omnifood logo" class="logo">
                  <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Food delivery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our cities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </nav>
          <div class="hero-text-box">
            <h1>Goodbye junk food.<br> Hello super healthy meals</h1>
            <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">I'm hungry</a>
            <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
          </div>
            
        </header>
        
        <section class="section-features">
          <div class="row">
              <h2>Get food fast &mdash; not fast food.</h2>
              <p class="long-copy">
               Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise! 
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                <h3>Up to 365 days/year</h3>
                  <p>
                  Never cook again! We really mean that. Our subscription plans include up to 365 days/year coverage. You can also choose to order more flexibly if that's your style.
                  </p>
                </div>
             <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                <h3>Ready in 20 minutes</h3>
                  <p>
                 You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.
                  </p>
                </div>
            <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                <h3>100% organic</h3>
                  <p>
                All our vegetables are fresh, organic and local. Animals are raised without added hormones or antibiotics. Good for your health, the environment, and it also tastes better!
                  </p>
                </div> 
              <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                <h3>Order anything</h3>
                  <p>
                We don't limit your creativity, which means you can order whatever you feel like. You can also choose from our menu containing over 100 delicious meals. It's up to you!
                  </p>
                </div> 
            </div>
        
        </section>
        
    
    </body>




</html>
```

```css
/*  SECTIONS  ============================================================================= */

.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  GROUPING  ============================================================================= */

.row {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
.row:before,
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
}
.row:after {
    clear:both;
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  /*margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;*/
        margin: 0;
 }
}

/*  GRID OF TWO   ============================================================================= */


.span-2-of-2 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span-1-of-2 {
 width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-2-of-2 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-1-of-2 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
}

/*  GRID OF THREE  ============================================================================= */

.span-3-of-3 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span-2-of-3 {
    width: 66.13%;
}

.span-1-of-3 {
    width: 32.26%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-3-of-3 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-2-of-3 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
    .span-1-of-3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/*  GRID OF FOUR  ============================================================================= */

.span-4-of-4 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span-3-of-4 {
    width: 74.6%;
}
.span-2-of-4 {
    width: 49.2%;
}
.span-1-of-4 {
    width: 23.8%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span-4-of-4 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 .span-3-of-4 {
  width: 100%; 
 }
    .span-2-of-4 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .span-1-of-4 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't include grid.css into your own example. i did https://jsfiddle.net/uj5c7zuv/ and the grid works

Comment: yeah...that was it! thats a lot man @Michael_B :)